# Error in TFLearn model for CNN text analysis

Tags: tflearn

I've tried to use Karan's  [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616292/how-to-load-and-retrain-tflean-model) TFlearn model "as is" as a template for CNN model for sentiment analysis, but I've got 2 strange errors:

1) there is no module **global_max_pool** in tflearn.layers.conv package (i've tried two tflearn packages with the same result, so I just used source code of it (all other modules were imported w/o problems).

2) ----> 5 branch1 = conv_1d(network, 128, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', regularizer="L2")
**AssertionError: Incoming Tensor shape must be 3-D**

Do you have any idea what is the reason? how I can overcome it?

Comment: It might have something to do with the version of tensorflow and tflearn. What versions do you have ?

Comment: I think you right, it seems tflearn is not kept up to date

Comment: Awesome! It happened to me a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

To help others, the error occurs due to old versions of TensorFlow and TFLearn. Please update to the latest version using:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tflearn
```